# removing commas between numbers and special characters in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list something like

```
['Scottish Investment Trust 2, 220 0.92, Financial Services – 6.97,% 750, 000, Ashmore 2, 554 1.06, 175, 000, Close Brothers 2, 704 1.12, 175, 704 1.12, 750, 000, IG Group 6, 034 2.50']
```

I am trying to remove commas between numbers and % using `.replace()` and `re.sub()` however it removes commas from all the places.

The list which I am trying to get should look like this.

```
['Scottish Investment Trust 2220, 0.92, Financial Services – 6.97% 750000, Ashmore 2554, 1.06, 175000, Close Brothers 2704, 1.12, 175704, 1.12, 750000, IG Group 6034, 2.50']
```

Trying to remove commas using `.replace()` however this removes all commas

```
list2 = [s.replace(',', '') for s in highlights]
```

Trying to remove commas using `re.sub()` however this also removes all commas.

```
list2 = ''.join(list1)
list2 = re.sub(',', '',list2)
```

How can it be done? Where exactly Am I making a mistake?

Comment: How can you express the logic that governs changing '2, 220, 0.92' to '2220, 0.92'?

Comment: "Where exactly Am I making a mistake?" Right now, the biggest mistake here is in failing to make the question clear. Please read [ask], and clarify: First off, both the input and desired output lists you show contain a single string; is that really what you want? Second, *what is the rule* that tells you which commas are thousands separators? *How do you know*, for example, that `175, 704` should remain `175, 704`, but `750, 000` should become `750000`? Third, *how did you try* to use `.replace()` and/or `re.sub()`? We can only tell you what is wrong with code that you actually show to us.

Comment: as far as 175,704 is concerned I have updated my desired list. As far as the code using .replace and re.sub is concerned I'll edit the question and you check that out for yourself.

Comment: I still don't understand what the rule is.

Comment: I have updated my question and have also shown how I have tried using replace and re.sub. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: You still haven't explained how '2, 220, 0.92' becomes '2220, 0.92'. What's the rule for this?

Comment: @JCaesar The IDEA is to remove a comma between numbers. If a number contains any another symbol then ignore the number.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. You "explanation" does not align with your required output

Comment: How come the `,` between `220` and `0.92` is a "comma between numbers", but the `,` between `2` and `220` isn't? And *why do you have input like this in the first place*? If you want to write a number with commas as thousands separators, that's all well and good, but normally one does not put a space after such a comma.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel to answer your questions the list mentioned in the question is a direct outcome of a code; apparently whatever is being highlighted from the pdf the code(using pymupdf,fitz) extracts.

Comment: @JCaesar I made changes to the to the list that I have. its 2, 220 0.92.

Comment: @technophile_3 is there still a space in your numbers like  2, 220 and 750, 000? If so, it's not a problem of removing commas between numbers?

Comment: Furthermore, the expected strings **adds** commas after replacements. I shall not try to answer unless what you specify is conformant with the example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules governing the process of getting from A->B are not clearly explained but can possibly be deduced from the sample input/output. This code does achieve that transformation but in the absence of a well-defined specification, it may not work in all cases.

```
ALIST = ['Scottish Investment Trust 2, 220 0.92, Financial Services – 6.97,% 750, 000, Ashmore 2, 554 1.06, 175, 000, Close Brothers 2, 704 1.12, 175, 704 1.12, 750, 000, IG Group 6, 034 2.50']
OLIST = []
for s in ALIST:
    r = []
    try:
        token = iter(s.split())
        while (t := next(token)):
            if t.endswith(',%'):
                r.append(t.replace(',', ''))
            else:
                if t.endswith(','):
                    try:
                        int(t[:-1])
                        n = next(token)
                        if n.endswith(','):
                            n = n[:-1]
                        t = t[:-1] + n + ','
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
                r.append(t)
    except StopIteration:
        pass

    OLIST.append(' '.join(r))
print(OLIST)
```

**Output:**

```
['Scottish Investment Trust 2220, 0.92, Financial Services – 6.97% 750000, Ashmore 2554, 1.06, 175000, Close Brothers 2704, 1.12, 175704, 1.12, 750000, IG Group 6034, 2.50']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this solves my problem; however the output is in a string and not a list.

Comment: And you don't know how to do that? I've edited my answer for you as you're obviously struggling with basic Python